# How do i add data to a specific column in datagridview?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have i already made 3 lists of elements that i want to insert on my datagridview,
[image]

but the problem is when i try to insert data on my datagrid a receive something like this,[image]

so to insert data i used the following code:

```
        IList<string> ruas = new List<string>();
        foreach (var element in Gdriver.FindElements(By.ClassName("search-title")))
        {
            //ruas.Add(element.Text);
            table.Rows.Add(element.Text);


        }


        IList<string> codps = new List<string>();
        foreach(var Codpelement in Gdriver.FindElements(By.ClassName("cp")))
        {

            table.Rows.Add("",Codpelement.Text);

        }

        IList<string> Distritos = new List<string>();
        foreach (var Distritoelement in Gdriver.FindElements(By.ClassName("local")))
        {


            //Distritos.Add(Distritoelement.Text);
            table.Rows.Add("","",Distritoelement.Text.Substring(Distritoelement.Text.LastIndexOf(',') + 1));

        }
```

Could you kindly, tell me a better way to make the data appear from top to bottom?

Thanks.

Comment: Better to create a datatable and then make datatable the datasource of DGV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you enter a single value per row. You should have three rows in total, but you have 3 * numberofcolumns rows. Instead of your current approach I recommend the following:

```
    IList<string> ruas = new List<string>();
    foreach (var element in Gdriver.FindElements(By.ClassName("search-title")))
    {
        ruas.Add(element.Text);
    }


    IList<string> codps = new List<string>();
    foreach(var Codpelement in Gdriver.FindElements(By.ClassName("cp")))
    {
        codps.Add(Codpelement.Text);
    }

    IList<string> Distritos = new List<string>();
    foreach (var Distritoelement in Gdriver.FindElements(By.ClassName("local")))
    {
        Distritos.Add(Distritoelement.Text.Substring(Distritoelement.Text.LastIndexOf(',') + 1));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ruas.Count; i++) {
        table.Rows.Add(ruas.ElementAt(i), codps.ElementAt(i), Distritos.ElementAt(i));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for aswering! Could you tell me, why in the first row of the collumn "Distritos", isn't shown any data?

Comment: @PedroAlvim you are welcome. It is difficult to tell without knowing the actual data you have for Distritos. It is possible that the Distrito of Rua do Monte ends with a comma and some white spaces after it, as in your algorithm we get the part of Distrito after the last comma, see: Distritoelement.Text.Substring(Distritoelement.Text.LastIndexOf(',') + 1)

Comment: I think selenium had a problem with the className selector, because i changed it to XPath and it worked just fine.